# This title is not a clue

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image: An image]

<sup><sup><sup>$\color{#FFFFFF}{\textsf{I am required to have text in my question.  This is not a clue.  Stop reading and look at the image.}}$</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: What is the question being asked?

Comment: @Alto as an [tag:enigmatic-puzzle], figuring that out is part of the puzzle

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be

> a representation of the cyclic group of order 4.
>
>  [image]

Comment: This is a start, but it is not the intended answer in itself.

Comment: @WW Well, you've given no extra information as what the intended answer is supposed to be, or even what form it's supposed to take. Do you want the words "Cayley diagram"? There's no more information to use in the picture other than the colors, which seem arbitrary.

Comment: There is additional information in the way it is presented.

Answer (score 3):

My immediate reaction to this is the same as Deusovi's. The best I can do for a further step is this:

> the diagram is somehow suggestive of those formalized country dances where people or couples stand in (perhaps) a square and carry out a sequence of moves announced by a caller. So is this a ghastly pun, whose point is that this is a *ceilidh diagram*?

I don't expect this is the intended answer, not least because

> a bit of googling *does* turn up some diagrammatic notations describing dances but they don't look much like the diagram here.

Comment: Oh, I *hope* that's the answer. That's a brilliantly terrible pun.